# How to find the date number for the first day of the current week on PHP

Tags: php, date

I need to find the date number for the first day of the current week. For example if the date is 05/06.2015 I want to get as a result 29/05/2015 where Monday is the firs day of the week. I'm not very familiar with PHP date functions because I'm new at it. Can someone show me how to find it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[strtotime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is a powerful function.

```
echo date("j/n/Y", strtotime('monday this week'));
```